# How to do std::string indexof in C++ that returns index of matching string?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I'm looking for a string indexof function from the std namespace that returns an integer of a matching string similar to the java function of the same name.   Something like:

```
std::string word = "bob";
int matchIndex = getAString().indexOf( word );
```

where getAString() is defined like this:

```
std::string getAString() { ... }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try the [`find`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/find) function.

Here is the example from the article I linked:

```
 string str1( "Alpha Beta Gamma Delta" );
 string::size_type loc = str1.find( "Omega", 0 );
 if( loc != string::npos ) {
   cout << "Found Omega at " << loc << endl;
 } else {
   cout << "Didn't find Omega" << endl;
 }
```

Comment: Is there a function for actually finding the _index_ at which the substring begins? I could subtract the beginning iterator, but is that necessary?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah `find` returns the index. The unsigned integer type `string::size_type` is just there to guarantee that the result of `find` fits into `loc`. (Think a really, really big index might not fit into an `int`.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181079/stringsize-type-instead-of-int

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the `std::basic_string<>` function template:

```
size_type find(const basic_string& s, size_type pos = 0) const;
```

This returns the index or `std::string::npos` if the string is not found.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear from your example what String you're searching for "bob" in, but here's how to search for a substring in C++ using [find](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/find).

```
string str1( "Alpha Beta Gamma Delta" );
string::size_type loc = str1.find( "Omega", 0 );

if( loc != string::npos )
{
   cout << "Found Omega at " << loc << endl;
}
else
{
   cout << "Didn't find Omega" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your example means, but for the stl string class, look into [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find.html) and [rfind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind.html)