# Declaring in for-loop for vector operations

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

Considering this code:

```
vector<double> student_grades(20);

for (vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < student_grades.size(); i++)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

What exactly is different about declaring `i` this way instead of just `int i = 0`?

Comment: Think about what happens if you have more than 2 billion students to process.

Comment: here's the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1181629/1663919

Comment: The link the others are giving shows it can be an unsigned int but also a long. The difference is not due to the size of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is different about declaring i this way instead of just int i = 0?

It ensures that the proper type is used - you are assuming that `vector<T>::size_type` is always the same as `int`, but this assumption is not correct. Depending on the implementation, it could also be something like `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long` or `size_t`.

By using `vector<T>::size_type`, your code remains portable across different implementations.

See also [vector<int>::size_type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/c-vectorintsize-type).

Answer (score 1):

`size_type` is a typedef inside the vector class, which gives the `vector` class a chance to decide what type to use for indexing. `int` has a max value of (typically, but not guaranteed - I think it's guaranteed to be at least 32767) of 2^31. Since sometimes we want larger vectors than 2 billion items [admittedly not that often, I suspect], it's useful for the type to be specified by the class itself.

This type is guaranteed to cover the range that the `vector` implementation itself can cope with. It is not too large [if you choose to use `long long` on a 32-bit system, it would be larger than what you need], and not too small. Of course, if you know you are only going to have 10 items, it probably doesn't matter.

It is also almost always a unsigned type. In some cases, that makes the indexing of arrays more efficient, which also helps performance a tiny bit.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<T>::size_type` is a `static` member of `std::vector`. I don't know why anybody would use it, for it can lead to confusion, I guess. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/c-vectorintsize-type) this his has already been answered on SO.

Comment: You are proposing **not** to use it? Isn't that the opposite of what the answers to your linked question says?

Comment: I believe it is confusing, and can't make a sense out of it. But for further reference I provided the link.

Answer (score 0):

> size_type is a (static) member type of the type vector. Usually,
>   it is a typedef for std::size_t, which itself is usually a typedef for
>   unsigned int or unsigned long long.

[Link to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/c-vectorintsize-type)

> The standard containers define size_type as a typedef to
>   Allocator::size_type (Allocator is a template parameter), which for
>   std::allocator is defined to be size_t.

[Link to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type)