# Trouble counting words

Tags: c++

I got an issue regarding wordcounting program. I would like the program to be able to tell me how many words,lines,character, unique lines, and unique words there are in a given string. However, I keep getting issues regarding this. Can someone please help me especially regarding the whitespace characters?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <set>
using std::set;

unsigned long countLines(const string& s)
{
int nl = 0;

for(int x =0; x<s.size(); x++)
{
    if(s[x] == "\0")
nl++;
}
return nl;

}

unsigned long countWords(const string& s)
{
    int nw = 0;
    char ws = " ";

    for (int x = 0; x<s.size(); x++)
    {
        if (s[x] == ws)
        {
            nw++;
        }
    }

    return nw;

}

unsigned long countChars(const string& s)
{
int nc = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < s.size(); x++)
{
    if ( s[x] != " ")
    {
        nc++;
    }
}

return nc++;
}

unsigned long countuline(const string& s, set<string>& wl)
{
wl.insert(s);
return wl.size(s);
}

unsigned long countuwords(const string& s, set<string>& wl)
{
int nuw = 0;
char ws = " ";
wl.insert(s);

for (int x = 0; x<s.size(); x++)
{
    if (s[x] == ws)
    {
        nuw++;
    }
}

return nuw;
}

int main()
{
string line;

while (getline(cin,line))
{
    cout << countLines(line) << "\t" << countWords(line) << "\t" << countChars(line) << endl;
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: For one thing, you don't seem to be using `s` in `countLines()`.

Comment: You should perhaps just start with counting the lines. At the moment it is all wrong. You're just reading one line at a time, and then returning 1 each time, so I imagine your program prints out thousands of 1s

Comment: What kind of issues? It would help if you were more specific

Comment: The thing is that I want the program to read a specific set of input with lines and such. Then the program will list out the number of lines, words, characters, unique lines, and unique words in that order with spaces between each. At the moment, I am trying to create a function for each so I'll be able to use it in the main function. However, right now I am stuck and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. s[x] == " " is not working either.

Comment: `countLines()` really isn't doing anything useful.  As Salgar said, the function is just returning 1 each time.  If you're looking for the number of newlines, you'll have to look for `\n` in `s`.

Comment: I just edited it, will that work? I believe \0 means the end of a string

Comment: Learn how to debug your programs:  http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/debug.php

Comment: For the loops, [I'd also suggest `std::string::size_type` instead of `int`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181079/stringsize-type-instead-of-int).

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not a problem, you could put the entire string in a stream and read it. String streams read words by default (Using space as split character):

```
unsigned int count_words(const std::string& str)
{
    std::stringstream ss( str );
    unsigned int count = 0;
    std::string aux_string;

    while( ss >> aux_string )
         count++;

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

countLines always return 1 and string s is not being used. You are always setting nl to zero and incrementing it by one before returning.

```
    int nl = 0;
```

countWords, what is the result for this sentence "Hello World!"?

Comment: How can I integrate the string into that though?

Comment: you don't, all countLines does is adding one to the total lines. So you can remove the countLines function,  add a counter in the main function, and increment it every time you call getline.