# vector<double>::size_type vs. double

Tags: c++, vector

Why would you use `vector<double>::size_type` in a `for loop` rather than just, say, `double`? I've never really messed with `C++` vectors before and I was reading [this website's tutorial on them](http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/vectors.html). The author writes their `for loop` as,

```
for (vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter marks for student #" << i+1
         << ": " << flush;
    cin >> student_marks[i];
}
```

I can see that it works both ways, but *why* would you use them in the above way rather than just simply declaring your counter (`i`) as a primitive type? I saw [this older SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181079/stringsize-type-instead-of-int?rq=1) but I'm still not sure.

Comment: `double` really isn't an ideal type for loop counters.

Comment: because `vector<double>::size_type != double` (My guess it is `size_t`)

Comment: @FDinoff, It's typically `size_t`, but free to not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your code to be portable and maintainable, you have to use the size_type defined
in the container to index.

If you want the 99% solution, then currently, at least on gcc, all size_types are nothing more
than typedefs of size_t (which is an unsigned int), so you could use size_t. But, understand
that this could change in the future and your code could stop working or stop compiling.

Comment: This is not guaranteed and it's typically `size_t`, which is probably not `unsigned int`.

Comment: But why couldn't you just state `unsigned int` then? Why even bother with the lengthy `vector<double>::size_type`?

Comment: @Matt, The latter ensures you have a type that can store all of the valid indices.

Comment: If you use `size_type` then your code still works on different compiler settings where the size is different

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned *integer*; it's not necessarily `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental types can be divided into floating point and arithmetic types. Floating point types are really bad to model an index, since the main purpose is to be able to represent values that are not integral in nature. What would be the result of indexing a vector with a value of say 1.75? Either you index into the vector at position 1 or 2, but there is no object at position 1.75.

A different issue arises with the range of the possible values that can be used to index the container. There are different integral types like `unsigned char` or `short` that while they naturally fit the purpose of indexing might have a range much smaller than the size of the container and thus cannot be used to access any position in the vector, and some might have values that are not valid indices, like -1. Both of these are issues with `double`: it can represent negative values which make no sense as an index, and it cannot precisely represent all of the values in an `uint64_t` (which is a common type for `size_type` in 64bit architectures).

The standard library requires that each container provides a nested type (or `typedef`) that can be used to index into the container. This will be an integral unsigned type of a large enough size to refer to any element in the container. Using the nested `typedef` means that whenever you build your program with a different implementation, in a different architecture or with a different compiler it will always be the right indexing type.