# C++ expected class-name before { token, an inheritance error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

KSetBase.h base class , an interface

```
#ifndef HW6_GTUSETBASE_H
#define HW6_GTUSETBASE_H

class KSet;

#include <cstddef>
namespace TU {
    template<typename T>
    class KSetBase {
    public:
        virtual bool empty() const = 0;

        virtual size_t size() const = 0; //int is not okay since unsigned also could be in.
        //comparisons would be not working if that was case
        //detailed
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181079/stringsize-type-instead-of-int

        virtual size_t max_size() const = 0;

        virtual void insert(T first, T second) = 0; //cift dondurmesi gerekli
        virtual void erase(T deleter) = 0;

        virtual void clear() = 0;

        virtual T find(T deneme) = 0;

        virtual size_t count(T testle) = 0;

        virtual T begin() = 0;

        virtual T end() = 0;

    protected:
        ~GTUSetBase() {
            //do nothing
        }

    };
}

#endif //HW6_GTUSETBASE_H
```

---

KSet.h (derived class)

```
#include "KSetBase.h"
#ifndef HW6_GTUSET_H
#define HW6_GTUSET_H


#include <memory>

using namespace std;
namespace TU {

    template<typename T>
    class KSet : public KSetBase {
    public:
        bool empty() const;

        size_t size() const;

        size_t max_size() const;

        void insert(T first);

        void erase(T deleter);

        void clear();

        T find(T deneme);

        size_t count(T testle);

        T begin();

        T end();

    protected:
        int hmany = 0;
        shared_ptr<T> set_harmony;


    };

}

#endif //HW6_GTUSET_H
```

I cant figure out what part of my code is wrong. I basically made a basic inheritance from interface class, which i implemented all functions in KSet.cpp. In theory nothing looks wrong but it gives 2 errors.

both in main.cpp and KSet.cpp

`class KSet : public KSetBase {` 
Error line is this.

I checked #ifndef and #defines, i thought about using forward declaration but i cant seems to work that out.I am really stuck with this problem. I searched whole web about it , in the end there's always a big error on syntax or something that is visible , but i can't figure out on mine. It's very short and simple code.

Comment: `KSetBase` is a class *template*, and templates can't be inherited. You can only inherit from a concrete class (or `struct`). `KSetBase<T>` *is* a concrete class.

Comment: Did you mean `: public KSetBase<T>` ?

Comment: On an unrelated note, even if the `KSetBase` destructor doesn't do anything, you should still make it `virtual`.

Comment: Shouldn't i use default destructor instead?

Comment: Probably (about the `default` constructor), but it should still be marked as `virtual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KSetBase` is a template class, if you inherit from it you must specify a template argument:

```
template<typename T>
    class KSet : public KSetBase<T>
```

In addition, it seems you have a typo in the base class destructor.

Comment: wow this was the mistake i made, such many thanks to you.It is interesting even a logical IDE like C-Lion can't seems to figure out this error.