# How to fix warning:implicit conversion changes signedness?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I am relatively new to c++ as this is my first semester in a computer science course, so please excuse any basic misunderstanding. This is my code to check to see if a phone number is in the correct format, however I am getting two warnings when compiling. Any help from someone more experienced than I am is much appreciated! Thank you.

The warnings are in line 25 and 17.

[image: (complete warnings)]

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cout << "Enter a seven-digit phone number in the the form 000 - 0000: ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << endl;

    string part1 = s.substr(0, 3);
    string part2 = s.substr(4, 7);
    string full = part1 + part2;

    int pos = s.find('-');
    int i = 0;

    if (s.length() == 8 && pos != -1) {
        while (i < 7) {
            if (!isdigit(full[i])) {
                cout << "The number is not in proper format" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
        cout << "The number is in proper format" << endl;
    } else
        cout << "The number is not in proper format" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string.find()` returns a [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) which is unsigned.

Comment: and the index operator `[]` receives a `size_t` instead of int, so `full[i]` first converts `i` to `size_t`

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mr.Mopp. I don't want to ask for code but could you please elaborate. I have read the size_t cppreference page but I'm still not sure how exactly to fix this.

Comment: I'm trying to define size_t but I'm getting more errors now. Is there a simple way to go about this I am not thinking of?

Comment: You don't need to define `size_t`. Just use it. `size_t pos = ...;` `size_t i = ...;`

Comment: I tried this as well too, however I can't compare integers of different signs in the line if (s.length() == 8 && pos != -1)

Comment: [`string.find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) does not return -1 on failure. It returns `string::npos`. While this may be defined as -1, it is an unsigned type. That may be confusing but cppreference explains: _Although the definition uses -1, size_type is an unsigned integer type, and the value of npos is the largest positive value it can hold, due to signed-to-unsigned implicit conversion. This is a portable way to specify the largest value of any unsigned type._

Comment: This has resolved my issue, I'm going to keep adding to this program but I'll be sure to look further into how this size_t stuff works. Thank you to everyone who offered their time and help!

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181079/stringsize-type-instead-of-int) what you're actually asking about?