# Converting Deterministic Path Code from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, code-conversion, native-code

Does anyone know how I can convert this (from C#) to C++?

```
string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ZigbeeCommUSB)).CodeBase);
location = location.Substring(location.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Thanks.

**EDIT: Additional Information**

This is to convert from C# to native C++.  If there is another way to get the file path of the currently executing executable, I am open to ideas.  Thanks.

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble with?  Are you converting from C# to Managed C++?  Or are you trying to convert to native C++?

Comment: Visual C++ ? or Standard C++ ?

Comment: This is for native C++.  I need to get the location of the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`Substring` in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)
- [Getting path of current directory ( will help you on the way )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory)
- [How to do `IndexOf` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651497/how-to-do-stdstring-indexof-in-c-that-returns-index-of-matching-string)
- You can use [Assembly.GetAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly.aspx) in C++ if you use Visual C++

**Example of Assembly.GetAssembly from the above link**

```
Assembly^ SampleAssembly;
// Instantiate a target object.
Int32 Integer1(0);
Type^ Type1;
// Set the Type instance to the target class type.
Type1 = Integer1.GetType();
// Instantiate an Assembly class to the assembly housing the Integer type.  
SampleAssembly = Assembly::GetAssembly( Integer1.GetType() );
// Gets the location of the assembly using file: protocol.
Console::WriteLine( "CodeBase= {0}", SampleAssembly->CodeBase );
```

If you combind the above, you will probably come a bit closer to what you want to do. **If** this is going to be done in Native C++, you will have a bit more problem, there is something called ["Fusion API"](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q317540) that might help you look for assemblies in the GAC.

Comment: Thanks, Filip.  I've added some additional details to my original post.

Comment: @Jim, Check my second point "Getting path of current directory", that `GetCurrentDir` and should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  Microsoft now calls the function `GetCurrentDirectory`.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the path of the current executable, use [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using a NULL hModule argument.