# How can I scan a string like this in c++?

Tags: c++

If I have input like this,

`apple+banana=3`

And I want to store `apple` in one string and `banana` in another string and `3` in an integer, how can I do it? How can I skip those `+` and `=` signs? Thanks!

Comment: Read the whole input and [split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c) it. Also [indexOf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651497/how-to-do-stdstring-indexof-in-c-that-returns-index-of-matching-string) and [substring()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) is a good choice.

Comment: it may help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 0):

[`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) takes an optional delimiter as a third argument, so you could do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a, b;
    int c;
    std::getline(std::cin, a, '+');
    std::getline(std::cin, b, '=');
    std::cin >> c;
}
```

Comment: And if it is only, `apple+banana`? How will I do it then? Thanks!